# Material UI / material-ui appbar leftnav toggle not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

i'm using meteor react-packages and i have the appbar displayed properly, but i can't get the nav toggle to work.  i'm using code straight out of examples and i even read the code in the material-ui repo and it's seems like it should be working.  what am i doing wrong?

```
let {AppBar, LeftNav} = mui

AppLayout = React.createClass({
  menuItems: [
    {route: '/profile/bio', text: 'bio'},
    {route: '/profile/photos', text: 'photos'},
    {route: '/profile/videos', text: 'videos'},
    {route: '/profile/filmography', text: 'filmography'},
    {route: '/profile/settings', text: 'settings'},
    {route: '/profile/accounts', text: 'accounts'}
  ],

  _toggle(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.refs.leftNav.toggle()
  },

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this._toggle} title='react+meteor'  />
        <LeftNav ref="leftNav" docked={false} menuItems={this.menuItems} />
        <AppView />
      </div>
   )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so in following the guide here: http://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client-npm/

i missed one part of the mui guide here: http://material-ui.com/#/get-started

here is my `lib/app.browserify.js` file:

```
// material ui
mui = require('material-ui')
injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin")
// Needed for onTouchTap
// Can go away when react 1.0 release
// Check this repo:
// https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin
injectTapEventPlugin()

// this is needed for material-ui styling to work properly
ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager()
React.initializeTouchEvents(true)
```

i was missing this line `injectTapEventPlugin()` which actually does the injection!  after i added that and refreshed the browser, the menu works perfectly.